# Select element through jQuery in sumo select plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, sumoselect.js

I am trying to select a value in sumoselect dropdown through jQuery using:

```
 $('select.multiple-select2')[0].sumo.selectItem(2);
```

Its not getting select.

Sumoselect - https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `selectItem` method as follows:

```
$('select.multiple-select2')[0].sumo.selectItem(2);
```

Have a look at documentation at https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/

There is no any method like `setItem` which you are trying.

Comment: Sorry vijayP, it was selectItem itself, but typo mistake from me, its also not working

Comment: could you please create a fiddle or snippet for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
 $('#_dropdownID')[0].sumo.selectItem(data[0].stringValue);
```

This is to get the data from SQL and matching with the dropdown options. it comes as this

```
success:function(data){
 $('#_dropdownID')[0].sumo.selectItem(data[0].stringValue);
}
```